# How to add data attribute to HTML element in JSX without any value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At first I had to add an attribute to a custom element/component, so I tried doing it here, but i can only add it to non-custom elements like div and input.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-16-966eq

```
const dAttribute = { "data-rr-mask": "" };
const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <h4>Context </h4>
    <FeatureContext {...dAttribute} name="Context" />
    <hr />
    <h4> Error2 Boundaries</h4>
    <FeatureErrorBoundaries />
    <hr />
    <h4> Fragment</h4>
    <h2>
      <FeatureFragment />
    </h2>
    <hr />
    <h4>Reference</h4>
    <FeatureRef />
    <hr />
    <h4>Portals</h4>
    <FeaturePortal />
    <hr />
    <h4>Life Cycle</h4>
    <FeatureLifeCycle />
  </div>
);

render(<App {...dAttribute} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Also, this attribute will finally be used on an HTML element and I need it to be without any value, e.g.: `<input data-rr-mask />` and another issue is that I have to add an empty string as value; otherwise, the application throws an error.

Is there a way to do it so that you don't get `"data-rr-mask"=''` inside the element

Comment: adding `data-rr-mask` to a component directly will treat it as props and won't be available on the DOM, if you want to use it. Can you also please share the use of this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT (based on comments, OP is actually looking for data attributes to be resolved without any value, on the generated HTML)**

In order to eliminate the value entirely for the generated HTML element, as a user commented on my answer, you just need to use an empty string for your data-attribute/prop.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input data-rr-mask="" /> {/* will be resolved to <input data-rr-mask> on the generated HTML code*/} 
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here is a working example of it.](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-neumann-4cmo3)

[Here is a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-keller-4x4d1) mixing both your requests.

---

(Original answer based on first request)

At first you must consider that every attribute you pass to a custom component, can then be found on components `props`.

So for example, if you pass a custom attribute on your `App` component named `data-rr-mask` you can then found it, under your `App`'s props:

```
const App = (props) => {
  console.log(props) // { "data-rr-mask": "foo" }

  return <div>
    <MySecondCustomComponent {...props} /> 
  </div>
};


render(<App data-rr-mask="foo" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And then again, in your `MySecondCustomComponent` under its `props` you can find your custom attribute.

Comment: What if you need to add a valueless attribute? Ex: <input data-rr-mask />

Comment: Just give it the value `true` :) `<App data-rr-mask={true} />`

Comment: So when you use it to an actual element, e.g. an input, it will be resolved to what you actually need.

Comment: I get: <input data-rr-mask="true" /> instead of <input data-rr-mask />

Comment: Ooo now I see. Doesn't this cover your case? Is `true` causing any problems? I'm not sure if you can achieve this with JSX. Whenever you try to apply an empty data attribute to JSX, it automatically assigns the value `true` to it, but it should act the same way as an empty does.

Comment: Ah, ok weird. I got a ticket telling me i need to absolutely make sure there's no value for the new attribute and our application is in React.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without setAttributes? I need to use an element called AutoComplete from a library and i am not allowed to modify it, and it uses a props called inputProps that populate the input field, which needs to have the custom attribute.

Comment: What custom library do you use? It should provide a `ref` for the actual input. e.g. `inputRef`

Comment: Oh yeah, I got ref={ref}. Do I do the same thing as you mentioned and replace myRef with ref?

Comment: Sure thing! Rename it to what fits you best.

Comment: Wouldn't just `<input data-rr-mask="" />` works? I tested it and it looks like there's no need for refs? It outputs correctly `<input data-rr-mask type="text" />`.

Comment: You are right man! What I was trying this whole time? I thought this was the first thing I've tried, but I must made a mistake. I'm updating my answer. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: It doesn't work, because ref is fed to the component via the forwardRef function. Is there a way to do this with a ref that comes from forwardRef?

Answer (score -2):

In my understanding a prop without a value is a boolean prop with value true.

So that means

```
<div someProp />
```

is the same as

```
<div someProp={true} />
```

Try if the following solves your problem:

```
const dAttribute = { "data-rr-mask": true };
```

See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes for more information on boolean HTML attributes.

Comment: The question is not about props, but about custom HTML attributes without a value.

Comment: And what might be the difference between a prop and a custom HTML attribute? Especially since in the example he is clearly not writing HTML but JSX ;) 
In the end what I said is also true for HTML attributes: no value means a boolean and true (like a flag).

Comment: See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: OP is asking about JSX, but he wants the final HTML to render something like `<input data-rr-mask />` which your answer doesn't address. A boolean prop will render `<input data-rr-mask="true" />`.